# Configuration for read-only/write within .NET TBBs

Tags: 2013, templating, configuration

I seem to remember there is a configuration setting in version 2011 which by default sets templates to have read-only access to the TOM.NET API. Is this still the case in 2013, and where can I set it to allow write access?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's still the case in 2013. You need to set `allowWriteOperationsInTemplates` attribute to true, to the element called `tridion.contentmanager.security` in `Tridion.ContentManager.config`

Comment: Thanks - I just found it in the documentation too, its in a bit of a weird place: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=BWCompatIssuesCM.xml&docid=concept_1453B827EA0C4607BA8A68AAB2E95CCC&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_1453B827EA0C4607BA8A68AAB2E95CCC